# Force stock captcha to random string?

Tags: captcha

Is there a setting to force the stock EE captcha to use a random string instead of the word list in /config/captcha.php?
I was able to do it by copying the random string generator from the captcha_helper.php file and use that in the captcha.php file to feed the array a random string.

Just wondering if there is some hidden configuration to do this instead of hacking a file.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a hidden config that I'm aware of...